# How to send enter 4 times in batch file?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am going to use AWS CLI to control AWS resources automatically on windows.
But I find the problem with AWS configure to press enter from cmd to run the next command. How do I automatically press enter from the .bat?
Thanks for your help.

for example,

`C:\>aws configure`

```
AWS Access Key ID [AKIAIOSFODNN7****]: (press enter)
AWS Secret Access Key [wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiC**]: (press enter)
Default region name [us-west-2]: (press enter)
Default output format [json]: (press enter)
run next command.
```

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808546/windows-expect-command-equivalent/27809559

Comment: As @harrymc noted, your syntax seems to suggest bash. Can you confirm what scripting language you are using?

Comment: @mtak it is .bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with pure cmd, you can create an empty textfile and place the 4 enters in there.

Now your command will be `command < textfile`

This basically means, run `command` and use textfile as input. You can put other text inside the textfile too and it will enter that as keystrokes to the command as well as the enters.

So lets say you have the file `C:\aws\enters.txt` that contains 4 enters, as such:

And your aws command is inside C:\aws too, you would type:

```
C:\>cd aws

C:\aws>aws configure < enters.txt
```

Comment: sorry, what does it mean? do you mean I can redirect the press enter *4 from the textfile?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means. I've updated my answer to make it more clear. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thank you, it works, amazing

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as solved by clicking the checkbox, so others know you no longer need help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

```
printf "\n\n\n\n" | aws configure
echo -e "\n\n\n\n" | aws configure
```

For more ways of passing Enter to a program see the post:
[Echo newline in Bash prints literal \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-newline-in-bash-prints-literal-n).

(Unfortunately, I don't have your environment for testing.)

Comment: The question clearly states `batch` file (and `.bat`). This is for `bash`

Comment: @mtak: "$ aws configure" is not Windows. The client computer might be Windows, but the server seems like Linux.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it's up to the OP to provide clarification.

Comment: @mtak you are right

Comment: @harrymc I am sorry for making misunderstanding on this, I change it to C:\>aws configure, anyway thanks for your advise.